# Why sacrifice the more advanced Jaeger?

Tags: pacific-rim

In the third act of Pacific Rim (2013), the protagonist forces hatch a plan to destroy The Breach by

> having Eureka Striker leap into the wormhole with a nuclear device attached to its back.

However, given that the Striker was the only Mark V and represented years of advancement over the Mark III Gipsy Danger, why wouldn't they do it the other way around?

I realize the answer to this is probably just "plot", but **has the related comics, novelization or anyone involved with the production of the film addressed this?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a hail-mary pass. The Breach is now fully dilated and the two Kaiju that have just come through aren't heading for shore, they're guarding what's gone from an occasional portal into a full blown beachhead.

Given that the purpose is to deliver the payload directly into the Breach, it makes sense to have the less important (and less powerful) Jeager run an interference pattern and have the more powerful and faster Jaeger deliver the actual nuke itself.

> ... Striker Eureka had her orders, and they weren’t to stand and
> fight. **The fastest Jaeger around, she covered a hell of a lot of
> ground considering the density of the water and the sludgy seafloor.**
> Still, she was running and Scunner was swimming, propelling itself
> largely with its tail and staying right on Striker’s heels, no matter
> what evasive action Pentecost and Chuck took.
>
> <sub><sup>[Pacific Rim - Official Novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17162161-pacific-rim)</sup></sub>

Anticipating that the Kaiju would attack anything approaching the rift, they chose the more agile and fastest available Jaeger to carry the bomb.

> Onboard sensors detected multiple small points of damage to Striker Eureka’s back and shoulders. **They dodged and wove, taking full advantage of their Jaeger’s agility and speed. Scunner couldn’t land a clean shot,** but Pentecost knew they wouldn’t be able to dodge forever. Striker Eureka couldn’t turn and fight, and even if she could have, they couldn’t open the K-Stunner ports this far underwater without causing fatal damage to Striker’s internal mechanisms.
>
> <sub><sup>[Pacific Rim - Official Novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17162161-pacific-rim)</sup></sub>